# Jquery Validation on Modal box loaded after page

Tags: php, jquery, validation, modal-dialog

So As Title says i have modal box which loads after the page load means it is loading after the Ajax Call and i want to validate the fields of this modal box.
for that i'm using the below code , as my HTML is not loaded in DOM :

```
$(document).on('click', ".add_style", function(e) {
        var style_name = "";
        style_name = $(".style_name").val();
        if($.trim(style_name).length == 0)
        {
            $("#style_id").parent('div').addClass('has-error');
            $(".title_error_msg").css("display","block");
            return false;
        }   
        else
        {
            console.log("In else");
            return false;
        }

    });
```

But I'm not able to get the values of field of modal form.
Please help, Thanks n advance.

Updated : 
Here is the part of the HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="style_id" name="style_id">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="style_name" name="style_name" placeholder="Style Name" class="form-control style_name">        <div style="display:none" id="Styles_style_name_em_" class="errorMessage"></div>        <label style="display:none;" class="control-label title_error_msg" for="inputError"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> Please enter Style Name</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: code shown looks fine assuming selectors are correct. Show corresponding html. Also check for any errors in browser console

Comment: @charlietfl Updated, please have a look.

Comment: logic doesn't make sense. The only event captured is `click` which will occur before user changes anything. try `change` or `blur` instead

Comment: @charlietfl `change` and `blur` is also not giving the value of field.

Comment: try using id selector instead of class. If there are more of same class will return value of the first one in page

Comment: I have tried with ID too, But not luck.